# Most important mathematical results in last 30 years

Tags: soft-question, big-list, gm.general-mathematics

Which results from the last 30 years, in any area of mathematics, do you think are the most important ones?

Specifically, which are the ones that will have more impact across all math and/or settle significant questions, in your opinion? It does not matter if they are big, lond-proofed results like a classification theorem, or little, elementary lemmas proved in a paragraph.

To keep this reasonable, I propose that every contributor posts at most 10 results.

Please, write one result per post, so that we can all vote properly and have a real ranking afterwards. Also, please don't just write the name, write a little description (hopefully, self-contained) and put some link if desirable.

(My personal aim with this question is to learn. I hope to be a bit better versed  after studying your answers!)

Comment: The Classification of Finite Simple Groups!

Comment: The proof of the modularity theorem.

Comment: @NickGill and SylvainJULIEN Please, add your answers as proper answers! And elaborate a bit if you can. The classification of finite simple groups could be controversial in this list, since it started in the 50s, but I would vote for it

Comment: @JoseBrox, I'll add an answer later if I get time... And someone else doesn't write it first! I think most people would agree that CFSG was really only completed with Aschbacher--Smith's work on quasithin groups. This work was announced in 2001 I believe, so I would argue that CFSG counts. Of course the genesis of CFSG is much older but the same is probably true of almost all recent mathematics, no?

Comment: This post has been "put on hold as primarily opinion-based". So now an educated opinion is a bad thing for us to have and share?

Comment: For 2016, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076565/

Comment: The ABC Conjecture.  :)

Comment: Jose, I haven't made up my mind about the merits of this question, but I think it's true that the "average" MO participant will not have an expert or even particularly educated opinion on what is most important, whereas the ranking would likely reflect a kind of average opinion on the matter. (Somewhere Feynman talks about the pernicious effect of averages and polls in cases where really expert opinion matters; in his case it was the ranking of school textbooks.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble On the contrary, in my opinion MO _should be_ the site where to ask this, since supposedly it reunites researchers and working mathematicians, not just a handful of people with some math knowledge and a lot of people with some math uncertainties (like MSE).

Comment: Jose: indeed, of all places I agree that MO would probably be one of the best places to ask, but that doesn't quite negate the point. Even if we exclude various undergraduates or non-professional (caliber) participants looking in, and consider actual working mathematicians, one could wonder whether the "average" of those has an educated opinion on "most important". But hey, I don't really want to argue; I'm just offering one possible POV on the reason for closure.

Comment: @JoseBrox, I see your point which is entirely valid... But I must admit that one thing that gave me pause with this question is that I would, generally speaking, prefer to avoid "ranking" mathematical work if I can. The system in which we work -- prestigious journals, getting grants, getting jobs -- forces this upon us at times and, to be honest, I don't much care for it. I know, of course, that sometimes there **are** good reasons to discriminate between different pieces of mathematics on grounds of value... but writing lists of this sort of thing is so subjective that it bothers me a bit...

Comment: @Jose , yes. On this forum, it is a bad thing to have and share an educated opinion. Primarily because  this place is intended as a repository for specific questions and answers to serve as a useful resource into the future, not a place to conduct opinion polls of limited temporal scope.  If you want to turn your encyclopedia into a personal scrapbook, that is up to you. This forum is the wrong place for your question.  Gerhard "That's Why There's A Blogosphere" Paseman, 2017.01.17.

Comment: Thank you for your views on the matter. I think they may be overlooking the fact that I specified what "important" means: with potential to be used across mathematics and potential to settle questions (not "to have settled a question" or "to have been published in wonderful journals"). This I consider as useful a resource into the future as any for my research.

Comment: @JoseBrox, why not just have a look at recent ICM plenary talks? That's going to give you a very similar list.

Comment: @HJRW That is a good idea, but I feel it falls short of my intentions. For example, I think that Alon's combinatorial nullstellensatz, maybe in combination with the polynomial method, qualifies as an answer to this question. I may be mistaken, but I think I won't find this in the plenary talks (it may be seen as "too tiny" or "too easy"), yet it serves to unblock long-standing interesting problems in an elementary manner, and I expect this trend to continue over the following years.

Comment: @JoseBrox -- your comment shows that there will be HUNDREDS of reasonable answers to this question.  I voted to close it as too opinion-based, but I also think it's far too broad/vague.

Comment: My question would be: important for _whom_? I know people for whom the Argyros-Haydon solution to the scalar plus compact question is the most important result they have seen since the late 1990s, because of the machinery it introduced. I would bet a large sum of money on the fact they have not heard of the combinatorial nulstellensatz.

Comment: FWIW I agree with @HJRW's comment. (This would have been an interesting discussion on tea.mathoverflow.net if we still used it)

Comment: @YemonChoi Your question has an obvious answer: important to whoever writes an answer. That is entirely the point: to have good working mathematicians stating which newest results they think are the main tools for today's and tomorrow's research, taken from the fields they are acquainted with, but that in their opinion can and will be used in broader contexts (ambitious, I know; but that is a reason _to ask and answer_ it, not to close it!).

Answer (score 11):

Taniyama, Shimura and later Weil conjectured around 60 years ago that the L-function of an elliptic curve arises from a modular form. This conjecture was known to entail the last Fermat theorem after pioneering works of Hellegouarch, Frey and Ribet. In 1994, after a very long and technical work made in isolation and relying on Galois representations, Wiles managed to prove this conjecture in the semi-stable case, which was enough to establish the veracity of the now called Fermat-Wiles theorem. Based on this work, an article published in 1999 by Breuil, Conrad, Diamond and Taylor establish the result in full generality.

This theorem is a tiny part of the Langlands program, dating from 1967.

Answer (score 10):

The proof of the **Milnor-Bloch-Kato conjecture** by *Vladimir Voevodsky* (Fields medal 2002):

One has a norm residue isomorphism $$\mathrm{K}^\mathrm{M}_n(k)/\ell \to \mathrm{H}^n(k, \mu_\ell^{\otimes n})$$ from Milnor $K$-theory to étale cohomology, $\ell$ invertible in $k$.

This is translated into a statement of the comparison of the cohomology of motivic complexes with respect to different topologies.

For $\ell = 2$, this is the Milnor conjecture. Even for this, Voevodsky got the Fields medal.

For $n = 0$, this is obvious, for $n = 1$, it follows from Hilbert's Theorem 90.  A corollary is that the Galois cohomology ring is generated by elements of degree $1$.

It implies the Beilinson-Lichtenbaum conjecture, a more general conjecture for varieties, not just fields.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/1568810830/ ...Monastyrsky's book *Modern Mathematics in the Light of the Fields Medals* [this comment, perhaps still useful, was made before an edit -- Todd Trimble].

Answer (score 6):

In discrete math:

Keevash's probabilisitic proof of Steiner's conjecture (On the Existence of Designs) is perhaps the biggest recent-ish result in combinatorics [due to the problem's ridiculously long pedigree].

But if you allow a little further back, I think Szemeredi's regularity lemma would have to take the cake for its outrageous applicability.

Answer (score 6):

Probably one of the major developments in homotopy theory is the [solution to the Kervaire invariant one problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3724) by Hill, Hopkins and Ravenel. It showcased the power of equivariant homotopy theory in solving a problem that a priori has nothing to do with it. In particular the idea to use the slice spectral sequence to get a handle on the homotopy fixed point spectral sequence of a certain spectrum is a real eye-opener.

Answer (score 6):

Perelman's proof of the Geometrization conjecture (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211159), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303109) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307245)) was the crowning achievement of decades of work.  It was the most important of Thurston's conjectures about the topology of 3-manifolds.

Oh, and I nearly forgot to mention that the Poincare Conjecture is a consequence.

Answer (score 5):

Agol's proof of the [Virtual Haken conjecture](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/documenta/vol-18/vol-18-eng.html) was a wonderful application of the tools developed by Wise and his coauthors in geometric group theory to 3-manifold topology.  The Virtual Haken conjecture, which can be thought of as the topological classification of compact 3-manifolds, is a fundamental result.

Agol's theorem:

> Every cubulable hyperbolic group is virtually special.

also has other dramatic consequences for hyperbolic groups.  It's arguably the most important theorem proved in both algebra *and* topology in the last five years.

Comment: I have learned from this post that "cubulable" is a word.

Answer (score 3):

Kahn--Markovic's proofs of the [Surface Subgroup conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5501) and the [Ehrenpreis conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1330).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going for:

> [Gauss's Class Number Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssClassNumberProblem.html)

solved for $m\le100$ by Watkins in 2004, in '[Class Numbers of Imaginary Quadratic Fields](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2004-73-246/S0025-5718-03-01517-5/S0025-5718-03-01517-5.pdf)'.

Comment: Why does this answer have been negatively received? The explanation will be instructive too!

Comment: @JoseBrox See [this blog post](https://galoisrepresentations.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/the-class-number-100-problem) for a discussion of this paper, and a criticism of this answers negative status.